# how to select a row where one of several columns equals a certain value?

Tags: sql, mysql

Say I have a table that includes column A, column B and column C.  How do I write I query that selects all rows where either column A OR column B OR column C equals a certain value? Thanks.

**Update:** I think forgot to mention my confusion.  Say there is another column (column 1) and I need to select based on the following logic:

...where Column1 = '..' AND (ColumnA='..' OR ColumnB='..' OR ColumnC='..')

Is it valid to group statements as I did above with parenthesis to get the desired logic?

Comment: To answer your edit, yes parentheses will enforce grouping.

Comment: based on your update, if you want it to work properly you *MUST* use parentheses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here...

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE COLUMNA=MyValue OR COLUMNB=MyValue OR COLUMNC=MyValue
```

Comment: Or just `MyValue IN (COLUMNA,COLUMNB,COLUMNC)`

Answer (score 5):

I prefer this way as its neater

```
select *
from mytable
where
myvalue in (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (Column1 = MyOtherValue) AND
      ((ColumnA = MyValue) OR (ColumnB = MyValue) OR (ColumnC = MyValue))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's valid to use parentheses. However, if you're searching multiple columns for the same value, you may want to consider normalizing the database.

Comment: +1, I completely missed that! ColumnA-ColumnB-ColumnC threw me off, if it were emailA-EmailB-EmailC it would have been more obvious