# SELECT range of values against multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query where I only need to specify a list of numbers/values once, but check if those are in either of two columns. Is this possible?

I'm bascically trying something like:

```
SELECT date
     , source
     , destination 
  FROM cdr 
 WHERE ('0400000000', '0411111111', '0422222222') IS IN source OR destination;
```

I can't find anything else on it, the closest I found was https://stackoverflow.com/a/1314192/2071729

To be clearer on my goal, I'm trying to avoid having the ranges in their twice, such like:

```
SELECT date
     , source
     , destination 
  from cdr 
 WHERE source IN ('0400000000', '0411111111', '0422222222') 
    OR destination IN ('0400000000', '0411111111', '0422222222');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb2f2/1/0)):

```
select date, source, destination from cdr
where exists (
  select * from (select 0 as n union all select 1) as a
  where case when n = 0 then cdr.source else cdr.destination end
    in ('0400000000', '0411111111', '0422222222')
)
```

Not sure if this produces an optimal query plan though... You have to check it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is so big you cannot specify it twice you could put the data into a temp table

```
Create temporary table myvals ( vals varchar(20) not null );

/*  Inserts to populate the temp table */

SELECT date, source, destination 
FROM cdr 
WHERE source in (select val from myvals) 
     destination in (select val from myvals);
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use like this WHERE ('0400000000', '0411111111', '0422222222')

> instead of you have to use where column1 = 00000 and column2=11111 and
>   so on....

Comment: I've appended clarification to my question.

Comment: what is you expected result?